# heroku run python manage.py makemigrations -a myapp takes forever

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have added this to my `setting.py`

```
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(default=DATABASE_URL)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

and yet when I run

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations -a myapp
```

it stucks in connecting process. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You should not be generating your migrations on heroku anyway, you should be _committing_ your migrations to source control (You should just run `migrate` on the server not generate the migrations each time)! What is the `-a` flag anyway? I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the docs (even looked at Django's source code)...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat so I need to makemigrations locally then push it to heroku, and then run migrate on Heroku? but I use docker compose locally, so I usually run docker-compose exec logistic python3 manage.py makemigrations

Comment: btw from what I got -a, --app APP  app to run command against

Comment: No, migrations should not be generated each time you start up a server (they should live with the code). For example consider this scenario: You have a server running and want to update your code a bit, this update involves new migrations, given that in heroku the filesystem is ephemeral your previous migration files are gone and since you now generate new migration files this includes changes that were already migrated to the database causing errors! Now you basically need to fix your migrations and database manually... Also no the app is a positional argument, there is no `-a` flag...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, the Heroku CLI _does_ have an `-a` / `--app` argument. I believe it is accepted with any CLI command, but it is [explicitly listed for `heroku run`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run) and many other commands.

Comment: Ah, so that is part of the heroku command, I assumed it was a flag for `manage.py`.